# Apache server doesn't start when mod_sm.so is loaded

Tags: solaris, apache-httpd, semaphore

I have an Apache 1.3 on a Sun machine (SunOS 5.10 Generic_138888-01 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-15000). If I keep the following two lines in httpd.conf, the server will not start:

`LoadModule sm_module "/cmsm_sw/epiapr1/netegrity/webagent/bin/mod_sm.so"

SmInitFile "/apache/conf/WebAgent.conf"`

This is all I get when I try to start Apache:

`:/apache/bin # ./apachectl start

1392: CSemCounter created a semaphore with ID 1157627995 using key 989855746.`

The mod_sm.so is the netegrity siteminder module (iPlanet).

Today there were some network issue (which were solved in the mean time) so I assume that this might have something to do. Maybe I should restart some services? I appreciate any help/hints.

Comment: does `apachectl configtest` give any clues?

Comment: The configuration test works fine. It says "OK". Anyway, the issue was fixed and it seems that the cause was this: on the local machine there was a netegrity web agent that was communicating with a policy server (I believe iPlanet) and the communication from the policy to my server failed (hence the apaching hangs at startup when sisteminder .so module was loaded). It was solved with a restart of the policy server. I know, it was impossible to tell this without knowing the configuration. Anyway, thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the part of the message "semaphore with ID 1157627995 using key 989855746", I'd say this module uses SysV IPC primitives.  Use the `ipcs` command to see how many semaphores, how many shared memory segments, etc exist.  The network problems may have caused the module to create semaphores and not delete them.  Or something.  I seem to recall that a pretty low limit on number of semaphores and/or shared memory segments exist by default, so you may be running afoul of those limits.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, indeed, there was a network issue. Trying to telnet from the client machine to the server machine on port 44441 failed.